Real-Time Notification System in Laravel for Receiving and Sending Messages
my problem in that notifications doesn't receive in reel time ,i can receive notifications when i reload my page ,but i want to receive notification without reload page .
this is my controller function that i can access to it by route 'newnotification':
public function getNotifications(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $demands = $user->unreadNotifications->where('type', '!=', 'App\Notifications\NewMessageNotification');
        $messages = $user->unreadNotifications->where('type', 'App\Notifications\NewMessageNotification');

        $response = [
            'demands' => $demands->map(function($notification) {
                $typeDemande = $notification->data['type_demande'] ?? 'Non spécifié';
                $status = $notification->data['status'] ?? null;
                $userName = $notification->data['user_name'] ?? 'Utilisateur non spécifié';

                $message = isset($status)
                    ? "Votre demande de type $typeDemande a été $status."
                    : "Nouvelle demande de type $typeDemande par l'utilisateur $userName";

                return [
                    'id' => $notification->id,
                    'type' => 'demand',
                    'message' => $message
                ];
            }),
            'messages' => $messages->map(function($notification) {
                $sender = $notification->data['sender'] ?? 'Expéditeur inconnu';
                return [
                    'id' => $notification->id,
                    'type' => 'message',
                    'message' => "Nouveau message de $sender"
                ];
            }),
            'countDemands' => $demands->count(),
            'countMessages' => $messages->count()
        ];

        return response()->json($response);
    }
      

also this is my blade:
code:
<!-- Notifications for Messages -->
<li class="nav-item dropdown pe-2 d-flex align-items-center">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link text-body p-0 position-relative" id="dropdownMenuButtonMessages" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fas fa-comments cursor-pointer"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-warning notification-count" id="notificationCountMessages">
            {{ auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('type', 'App\Notifications\NewMessageNotification')->count() }}
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end px-2 py-3 me-sm-n4 scrollable-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButtonMessages" id="notificationListMessages">
        @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('type', 'App\Notifications\NewMessageNotification') as $notification)
            <li class="mb-2 notification-item" data-id="{{ $notification->id }}" data-type="message">
                <a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" href="{{ route('notifications.redirect', $notification->id) }}">
                    <div class="d-flex py-1">
                        <div class="my-auto">
                            <img src="{{ asset('assets/auth/img/team-2.jpg') }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                            <h6 class="text-sm font-weight-normal mb-1">
                                Nouveau message de {{ $notification->data['sender'] }}
                            </h6>
                            <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">
                                <i class="fas fa-clock me-1"></i>
                                {{ $notification->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</li>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const notificationListDemands = document.getElementById('notificationListDemands');
    const notificationCountDemands = document.getElementById('notificationCountDemands');
    const notificationListMessages = document.getElementById('notificationListMessages');
    const notificationCountMessages = document.getElementById('notificationCountMessages');

    function updateNotifications() {
        fetch('{{ route('newnotifications') }}', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Update demands
            const demandsHtml = data.demands.map(notification => `
                <li class="mb-2 notification-item" data-id="${notification.id}" data-type="${notification.type}">
                    <a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" href="/demands/${notification.id}">
                        <div class="d-flex py-1">
                            <div class="my-auto">
                                <img src="{{ asset('assets/auth/img/team-2.jpg') }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                                <h6 class="text-sm font-weight-normal mb-1">${notification.message}</h6>
                                <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">
                                    <i class="fas fa-clock me-1"></i>
                                    ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            `).join('');
            notificationListDemands.innerHTML = demandsHtml;
            notificationCountDemands.innerText = data.countDemands || '';
            if (data.countDemands <= 0) {
                notificationCountDemands.style.display = 'none';
            }

            // Update messages
            const messagesHtml = data.messages.map(notification => `
                <li class="mb-2 notification-item" data-id="${notification.id}" data-type="${notification.type}">
                    <a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" href="/conversations/show/${notification.id}">
                        <div class="d-flex py-1">
                            <div class="my-auto">
                                <img src="{{ asset('assets/auth/img/team-2.jpg') }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                                <h6 class="text-sm font-weight-normal mb-1">${notification.message}</h6>
                                <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">
                                    <i class="fas fa-clock me-1"></i>
                                    ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            `).join('');
            notificationListMessages.innerHTML = messagesHtml;
            notificationCountMessages.innerText = data.countMessages || '';
            if (data.countMessages <= 0) {
                notificationCountMessages.style.display = 'none';
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

    setInterval(updateNotifications, 5000); // Check for new notifications every 5 seconds

    function markAsReadAndRedirect(notificationItem, type) {
        const notificationId = notificationItem.dataset.id;

        fetch(`/notifications/mark-as-read/${notificationId}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                notificationItem.remove();
                let countElement;
                if (type === 'demand') {
                    countElement = notificationCountDemands;
                } else if (type === 'message') {
                    countElement = notificationCountMessages;
                }
                const newCount = parseInt(countElement.innerText) - 1;
                countElement.innerText = newCount > 0 ? newCount : '';
                if (newCount <= 0) {
                    countElement.style.display = 'none';
                }

                if (type === 'message') {
                    window.location.href = `/conversations/show/${data.conversation_id}`;
                } else if (type === 'demand') {
                    window.location.href = `/demands/${notificationId}`;
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

    if (notificationListDemands) {
        notificationListDemands.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const notificationItem = e.target.closest('.notification-item');
            if (notificationItem) {
                markAsReadAndRedirect(notificationItem, 'demand');
            }
        });
    }

    if (notificationListMessages) {
        notificationListMessages.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const notificationItem = e.target.closest('.notification-item');
            if (notificationItem) {
                markAsReadAndRedirect(notificationItem, 'message');
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>

i try using ajax but function updatenotifications that can set interval every 5 second reload notifications but i didn't resolve it.if  you can help me please :')

;););):):):):):)

<nav class="navbar navbar-main navbar-expand-lg px-0 mx-4 shadow-none border-radius-xl" id="navbarBlur" data-scroll="true">
<div class="container-fluid py-1 px-3 ">
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb bg-transparent mb-0 pb-0 pt-1 px-0 me-sm-6 me-5">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm"><a class="opacity-5 text-dark" href="javascript:;">Pages</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm text-dark active" aria-current="page">Dashboard</li>
    </ol>
    <h6 class="font-weight-bolder mb-0">Dashboard</h6>
  </nav>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mt-sm-0 mt-2 me-md-0 me-sm-4 " id="navbar">
    <!--
    <div class="ms-md-auto pe-md-3 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
          <label class="form-label">Type here...</label>
          <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." oninput="searchText()">
        </div>
    </div>-->
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mb-0 me-3" target="_blank" href="https://www.creative-tim.com/builder?ref=navbar-material-dashboard">About Province</a>
      </li>
      <li class="mt-2">
        <a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard" data-icon="octicon-star" data-size="large" data-show-count="true" aria-label="Star creativetimofficial/material-dashboard on GitHub">Star</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-xl-none ps-3 d-flex align-items-center">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link text-body p-0" id="iconNavbarSidenav">
          <div class="sidenav-toggler-inner">
            <i class="sidenav-toggler-line"></i>
            <i class="sidenav-toggler-line"></i>
            <i class="sidenav-toggler-line"></i>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3 d-flex align-items-center">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link text-body p-0">
          <i class="fas fa-cog fixed-plugin-button-nav cursor-pointer"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <!-- Demand Notifications -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown pe-2 d-flex align-items-center me-3">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link text-body p-0 position-relative" id="dropdownMenuButtonDemands" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-bell cursor-pointer"></i>
          <span class="badge badge-warning notification-count" id="notificationCountDemands">{{ auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->whereIn('type', ['App\Notifications\DemandeStatusConfirmation', 'App\Notifications\DemandeCreated'])->count() }}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu dropdown-menu-end px-2 py-3 me-sm-n4" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButtonDemands" id="notificationListDemands">
            @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->whereIn('type', ['App\Notifications\DemandeStatusConfirmation', 'App\Notifications\DemandeCreated']) as $notification)
              <li class="mb-2 notification-item" data-id="{{ $notification->id }}" data-type="demand">
                  <a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" href="{{ route('notifications.show', $notification->id) }}">
                      <div class="d-flex py-1">
                          <div class="my-auto">
                              <img src="{{ asset('assets/auth/img/team-2.jpg') }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3">
                          </div>
                          <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                              <h6 class="text-sm font-weight-normal mb-1">
                                  @if(isset($notification->data['status']))
                                      Votre demande de type {{ $notification->data['type_demande'] }} a été {{ $notification->data['status'] }}.
                                  @else
                                      Nouvelle demande de type {{ $notification->data['type_demande'] }} par l'utilisateur {{ $notification->data['user_name'] }}
                                  @endif
                              </h6>
                              <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">
                                  <i class="fas fa-clock me-1"></i>
                                  {{ $notification->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </li>

      <!-- Notifications for Messages -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown pe-2 d-flex align-items-center">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link text-body p-0 position-relative" id="dropdownMenuButtonMessages" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-comments cursor-pointer"></i>
          <span class="badge badge-warning notification-count" id="notificationCountMessages">{{ auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('type', 'App\Notifications\NewMessageNotification')->count() }}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end px-2 py-3 me-sm-n4 scrollable-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButtonMessages" id="notificationListMessages">
          @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('type', 'App\Notifications\NewMessageNotification') as $notification)
              <li class="mb-2 notification-item" data-id="{{ $notification->id }}" data-type="message">
                  <a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" href="{{ route('notifications.redirect', $notification->id) }}">
                      <div class="d-flex py-1">
                          <div class="my-auto">
                              <img src="{{ asset('assets/auth/img/team-2.jpg') }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3">
                          </div>
                          <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                              <h6 class="text-sm font-weight-normal mb-1">
                                Nouveau message de {{ $notification->data['sender'] }}
                              </h6>
                              <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">
                                  <i class="fas fa-clock me-1"></i>
                                  {{ $notification->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- Notifications for Public Messages -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown pe-2 d-flex align-items-center">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link text-body p-0 position-relative" id="dropdownMenuButtonPublicMessages" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="fas fa-globe cursor-pointer"></i>
          <span class="badge badge-warning notification-count" id="notificationCountPublicMessages">{{ auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('type', 'App\Notifications\NewNotificationPublic')->count() }}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end px-2 py-3 me-sm-n4 scrollable-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButtonPublicMessages" id="notificationListPublicMessages">
          @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('type', 'App\Notifications\NewNotificationPublic') as $notification)
              <li class="mb-2 notification-item" data-id="{{ $notification->id }}" data-type="public_message">
                  <a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" href="{{ route('notifications.redirect', $notification->id) }}">
                      <div class="d-flex py-1">
                          <div class="my-auto">
                              <img src="{{ asset('assets/auth/img/team-2.jpg') }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3">
                          </div>
                          <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                              <h6 class="text-sm font-weight-normal mb-1">
                                Nouveau message public de {{ $notification->data['sender'] }}
                              </h6>
                              <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">
                                  <i class="fas fa-clock me-1"></i>
                                  {{ $notification->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </a>
              </li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </li>          
      
      <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
        <a class="nav-link text-body font-weight-bold px-0" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
           onclick="event.preventDefault();
           document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
          <i class="fas fa-user me-sm-1"></i>
          <span class="d-sm-inline d-none">Sign Out</span>
        </a>
        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
          @csrf
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

js:
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const notificationListDemands = document.getElementById('notificationListDemands');
    const notificationCountDemands = document.getElementById('notificationCountDemands');
    const notificationListMessages = document.getElementById('notificationListMessages');
    const notificationCountMessages = document.getElementById('notificationCountMessages');
    const notificationListPublicMessages = document.getElementById('notificationListPublicMessages');
    const notificationCountPublicMessages = document.getElementById('notificationCountPublicMessages');
    var authUserId = {{ json_encode(auth()->id()) }};

    function addNotification(notification, type) {
        const notificationHtml = `
            <li class="mb-2 notification-item" data-id="${notification.id}" data-type="${type}">
                <a class="dropdown-item border-radius-md" href="/notifications/redirect/${notification.id}">
                    <div class="d-flex py-1">
                        <div class="my-auto">
                            <img src="{{ asset('assets/auth/img/team-2.jpg') }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                            <h6 class="text-sm font-weight-normal mb-1">${notification.data.message}</h6>
                            <p class="text-xs text-secondary mb-0">
                                <i class="fas fa-clock me-1"></i>
                                ${notification.created_at}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        `;

        if (type === 'demand') {
            notificationListDemands.innerHTML += notificationHtml;
            notificationCountDemands.innerText = parseInt(notificationCountDemands.innerText) + 1;
            notificationCountDemands.style.display = 'block';
        } else if (type === 'message') {
            notificationListMessages.innerHTML += notificationHtml;
            notificationCountMessages.innerText = parseInt(notificationCountMessages.innerText) + 1;
            notificationCountMessages.style.display = 'block';
        } else if (type === 'public_message') {
            notificationListPublicMessages.innerHTML += notificationHtml;
            notificationCountPublicMessages.innerText = parseInt(notificationCountPublicMessages.innerText) + 1;
            notificationCountPublicMessages.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    Echo.private('App.Models.User.' + authUserId)
        .notification((notification) => {
            if (notification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\DemandeStatusConfirmation' || notification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\DemandeCreated') {
                addNotification(notification, 'demand');
            } else if (notification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\NewMessageNotification') {
                addNotification(notification, 'message');
            } else if (notification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\NewNotificationPublic') {
                addNotification(notification, 'public_message');
            }
            console.log(notification,'new notification');
    });


    function markAsReadAndRedirect(notificationItem, type) {
        const notificationId = notificationItem.dataset.id;

        fetch(/notifications/mark-as-read/${notificationId}, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                notificationItem.remove();
                let countElement;
                if (type === 'demand') {
                    countElement = notificationCountDemands;
                } else if (type === 'message') {
                    countElement = notificationCountMessages;
                } else if (type === 'public_message') {
                    countElement = notificationCountPublicMessages;
                }
                const newCount = parseInt(countElement.innerText) - 1;
                countElement.innerText = newCount > 0 ? newCount : '';
                if (newCount <= 0) {
                    countElement.style.display = 'none';
                }

                if (type === 'message') {
                    window.location.href = /conversations/show/${data.conversation_id};
                } else if (type === 'demand') {
                    window.location.href = /demands/${notificationId};
                } else if (type === 'public_message') {
                    window.location.href = /public-messages/${notificationId};
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

    if (notificationListDemands) {
        notificationListDemands.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const notificationItem = e.target.closest('.notification-item');
            if (notificationItem) {
                markAsReadAndRedirect(notificationItem, 'demand');
            }
        });
    }

    if (notificationListMessages) {
        notificationListMessages.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const notificationItem = e.target.closest('.notification-item');
            if (notificationItem) {
                markAsReadAndRedirect(notificationItem, 'message');
            }
        });
    }

    if (notificationListPublicMessages) {
        notificationListPublicMessages.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const notificationItem = e.target.closest('.notification-item');
            if (notificationItem) {
                markAsReadAndRedirect(notificationItem, 'public_message');
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>

there are my modification by using pusher ,but notifiactions not realtime

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
